# Quaternion or 3 Angles, reaction from collision. 3D

Tags: javascript, math, 3d, geometry, game-physics

I have coded a simple game with a ship, and have basic collision detection working. but I am struggling to calculate an efficient reaction from a collision.

The ships rotation is represented by a quaternion Q(w,x,y,z).

It's position is a coordinate P(x,y,z).

The collision on the surface is a coordinate C(x,y,z).

The direction it will slide along the surface after the collision is a unit vector S(x,y,z).

The surface normal is unit vector N(x,y,z).

The game has six degrees of freedom, and there is no particular world 'up' direction.

How do I calculate the correct rotation to apply to the ship, so that it faces direction S? *whilst minimizing the change in the ships local 'up' direction.
Any bits of pseudo code or pointers to a math explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Currently I am calculating a quaternion from the slide direction and just applying it to the ship, but obviously the 'up' direction isnt preserved.

:S

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**

It is now working.

Solved by calculating the Quaternion between two vectors (the ships 'Fwd' direction, and the Slide vector (S)), and then multiplying that Quaternion by the current ships rotation (Q).

```
// quaternion from two vectors
quat quat::fromtwovectors(vec3 u, vec3 v) {

    vec3 w = cross(u, v);
    quat q = quat( dot(u, v), w.x, w.y, w.z);
    q.w += q.magnitude();

    return normalize(q);

}
```